# Can variable be passing by function (react js)？

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I wrote a class component and mutilple functions in it(class) , but don't know how variable be passing between different function.

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    stringA:null,
    stringB:null
  };

 set_A = (event) =>{
      const stringA = 'text';
 }
 copy_A = (event) =>{
      const stringB = stringA;
 }

 render() {
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={this.set_A} type="click">set</button>
      <button onClick={this.copy_A} type="click">copy</button>
    </>
  );}
}
export default App;
```

I reference this docs , but it only said function component without class component.
https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-function-component

or, are state and props not a kind of variable？

Answer (score 3):

You access your properties with `this.props` and your state with `this.state`. You change state by calling `setState` which accepts partial states and merges them into the full state. It also triggers a re-render so that state changes can be seen in the UI.

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    stringA:null,
    stringB:null
  };

  set_A = (event) => {
    this.setState({ stringA: 'text' });
  }
  copy_A = (event) => {
    this.setState({ stringB: this.state.stringA });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.set_A} type="click">set</button>
        <button onClick={this.copy_A} type="click">copy</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't even think of mentioning the re-render on the change from props and state.

Comment: thank your answer , but when I add `console.log(stringB)` in `copy_A` function , it show a gray text of `undefined` in JS-Console.

Comment: Sorry ,also it happend a problem , that in `copy_A` function , if i add `this.setState({ stringB: this.state.stringA });`
, it show error **'stringA' is not defined no-undef**

Comment: does it need to be `this.state` I don't know what your Babel ecosystem looks like but the Class React is particular about `this` even if you set it up not to have a constructor and auto binding.

Comment: First heard Babel ecosystem , the react version I using is `npm create-react-app my-app` , It doesn't have much plugin in it , I think I will check Babel ecosystem you said.

Answer (score 1):

So in React, you would not be assigning a value to a variable like that. You would be utilizing State functionality. For Class-based React you would be using `this.setState({stringA: 'text'})`
or
`this.setState({stringB: stringA})`

Once the values are in the state you can access them anywhere in the component from the state object `this.state.stringB` for instance would have the value that was set once you had clicked on `copy` button

Example

```js
  set_A = (event) => {
    this.setState({ stringA: 'text' });
    console.log(this.state.stringB)
  }
  copy_A = (event) => {
    this.setState({ stringB: this.state.stringA });
  }
```

React Documentation is also a great resource to reference for Class and Function based component behaviors. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to reach out if there are other questions you have.

Answer (score 1):

You change state by calling ***setState*** in class based components
Try this :

```
class App extends Component { 
       state = { stringA:null, stringB:null }; 
       set_A = (e) => { 
             this.setState({...state, stringA: 'text' });
        } 
       copy_A = (e) => { 
             this.setState({ ...state,stringB: this.state.stringA });
       } 
      render() {
             return ( 
                    <> 
                      <button onClick={this.set_A} type="click">set</button> 
                      <button onClick={this.copy_A} type="click">copy</button>
                    </>
             );
       } 
} 
export default App;
```

Use ***the spread operator***  `{...state}` to change only the targeted piece of state you want to change with no change in the other pieces of the state.